# How to open a tkinter script that calls a different script within the same directory?

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry for the confusing question. I am working on a GUI and backend of a program that takes information from the gmail-api makes it into a text file. The back end and GUI(Tkinter) are working perfectly but through the python3 shell. When I just click on the python script within the directory a black command prompt appears and then disappears.

When I click on a prototype I have of the GUI that does not call another script but a text file, the GUI pops up perfectly.
This is after I used pyinstaller to make it an executable.

My end goal is to make the whole GUI and back end an executable file.

I was wondering if anyone knows why this happens. I think it might be because of it having to call another script...but I am not sure.

Sorry again for the confusing question and wordy explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to go to the terminal after you've intalled pyinstaller and run this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole yourtkinter.py
```

Explanation:

**--onefile** : Optional here, more comfortable for tiny tkinter projects.

**--noconsole** : Will solve your command line opening issue.

Find here more about the pyinstaller package:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: so if the other script the gui calls is in the same file as the .exe it should work?

Comment: You mean the text file you fill from Gmail API scraping?
Yes,
I would put every important "dependent" file in the same directory and call it from here.
Of course always keep the exe and the dependency files in the same folder

Comment: more, the other script the gui calls the main() of

Comment: This is how you want to import everything:
from .importantfileone import * , 
from .importantfiletwo import * , 
from .importantfilethree import *

Comment: ok, so with the "." before the name of the script being called? sorry for all the quesitons

Comment: once I have the import correct, when I use pyinstaller on the gui. After it is complete should I add to the specs file the documents that get called and the other script?

Comment: I am very sorry for not being as confident as I could be.

Comment: 1) The dot will do the trick

2) This should work when you call everything with '.' in the beggining

3) This is the way me and you learn code better. So be confident. Good luck

Comment: sorry for one more question. Would I rename the script called by the gui to have a period in the beginning or is it something changed in the spec file?

Comment: I dont recommend to rename the dependent files. You can rename the .exe file. And unfortunately im not sure about the spec file change. My guess would be No.

Comment: I will just use [from getter import main]?

Comment: ok, you helped me a lot already. I will stop asking. I think I can get it now. Thank you again.